# Creating PHP multiplication table with user input

Tags: php, html

I am creating form where the user can input a integer and get the multiplications (1-10) of that number. Here is my web form for user input:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Assignment 9.1</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="black" text="white">
    <form method="post" action="table.php"
        <strong>Enter No:</strong>
        <input type="text" name="num" size="10">
        <input type="submit" value="Get Table">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The table I have created is this:

```
<?php
$num = $_POST['num'];
if($num)
(
    for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
    (
        $mul = $num * $i;
        echo "$num * $i = $mul<br>";
    )
)
else
(
    echo "Invalid Entry!";
)
?>
```

I am getting an error for the table. The error is for line 5 (FOR). I have no idea why I am getting this error. Can anyone Help?

Comment: Not sure why this didn't post. Here is the web form that allows the user to input a number. 

    <html>
 <head>
  <title>Assignment 9.1</title>
 </head>
 <body bgcolor="black" text="white">
  <form method="post" action="table.php"
   <strong>Enter No:</strong>
   <input type="text" name="num" size="10">
   <input type="submit" value="Get Table">
  </form>
 </body>
    </html>

Comment: A block of code needs an empty line before it - StackOverflow wasn't recognising it as a code block and therefore trimmed out the HTML.

Comment: First, you need to close your form tag like so: `<form method="post" action="table.php">`.  That is unrelated to your problem though.  Also, I don't know who taught you PHP, but you always use curly braces after statements such as `if` and `for`.  Not parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Blocks of code are marked with curly brackets `{ ... }`, you are currently using parentheses `( ... )`

As far as I can tell, that's pretty much the only thing wrong with it. You might want to add a bit of validation:

```
$num = isset($_POST['num']) ? intval($_POST['num']) : 0;
```

But that'd just a touch-up. The brackets are your actual problem.

Comment: You're welcome - well done for getting so close to correct :) Seeing your question brought back memories of my early programming days... I could never remember when to use `()`, `{}` or `[]` XD

Answer (score 0):

You need to use {} instead () in the **for** and **if**.

Like this:

```
<?php
$num = $_POST['num'];
if($num)
{
    for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
    {
        $mul = $num * $i;
        echo "$num * $i = $mul<br>";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid Entry!";
}
?>
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You are using parentheses when you should be using braces. Try this...

```
<?php
$num = $_POST['num'];
if($num)
{
    for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
    {
        $mul = $num * $i;
        echo "$num * $i = $mul<br>";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid Entry!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
save the file as table.php and run working 100%
 <html>
<head><title>Table</title></head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
<center><input type="text" name="number" size="20" > </center>    <br>
<center><input type="submit" name="table" value="get table"> </center>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
$num=$_POST['number'];
if($num<=20)
{
  for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
  {
    $mul=$num*$i;
    echo "<center>$mul </center><br>";
   }
}
  else
  {
  echo "<center>envalid entry</center>";
   }


?>
```

---

```
<html>

<head><title>Table</title></head>

<body>

<form action="" method="POST">

<center><input type="text" name="number" size="20" > </center>    <br>

<center><input type="submit" name="table" value="get table"> </center>

</form>

</body>

</html>

<?php

$num=$_POST['number'];

if($num<=20)

{

  for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)

  {

    $mul=$num*$i;

    echo "<center>$mul <br></center>";

   }

}

  else

  {

  echo "<center>envalid entry</center>";

   }

?>
```